# Levinson Recursion for Tall (Non Square) Toeplitz Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, toeplitz-matrices

Given a tall non square [Toeplitz Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) $ H $, how could one solve:

$$ y = H x $$

In the general case it would be generated by (MATLAB Code):

```
numRows = 10; %<! Or any other number
numCols = 20; %<! Or any other number larger than 'numCols'
vR = randn(numRows, 1);
vC = randn(numCols, 1);
mH = toeplitz(vC, vR);
```

Since the Matrix is tall (Not square), I'm after the least squares solution:

$$ \arg \min_{x} {\left\| H x - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} $$

I have implemented the [Levinson Recursion](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Projects/tree/master/LevinsonRecursion) for the square case yet I'd like to know if there is an extension to it for the case the [Toeplitz matrix isn't square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103919).

Comment: Do you need to solve it exactly? Otherwise maybe iterative methods could get good properties by using the structure somehow.

Comment: @mathreadler, As long as they are faster than the general `\` operator (Namely *QR* solver) I'm OK with it.